# Bomber's Discovery and Cytillesh Bombs

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a Rogue who has taken the [Bomber](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-su) Rogue Talent already and is considering taking [Bomber's Discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo---rogue-talents/bomber-s-discovery-su) in the near future. The Bomber rules are as follows:

> A rogue with this talent can make a number of bombs per day equal to
>   her Intelligence modifier (minimum 1). These bombs act as alchemist's
>   bombs, except they deal damage equal to the damage dealt by the
>   rogue's sneak attack (the rogue doesn't add her Intelligence modifier
>   to this damage).

Unfortunately, the Bomber's Discovery talent doesn't give a large pool of Discoveries to choose from as it doesn't allow a Rogue to bypass the Alchemist level requirements, so I need to get creative with what is available!

So what happens if my Rogue take [Cytillesh Bombs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/cytillesh-bomb) as their Discovery?

> When the alchemist creates a bomb, he can infuse it with cytillesh
>   extract. Cytillesh bombs deal 1d4 points of damage, plus 1d4 points of
>   damage for every odd-numbered level, instead of 1d6. Creatures that
>   take a direct hit from a cytillesh bomb are sickened for 1 round per
>   alchemist level unless they succeed at Fortitude saves. If a creature
>   is rendered unconscious from this bomb or any other attack before it
>   is able to remove the sickened condition, the victim loses all memory
>   from the last hour and cannot form new memories for 8 hours.

How does this Discovery interact with the Bombs from the Bomber talent?

- What is the damage value of the Bombs? (Keeping in mind that those
  created by Bomber have damage equal to Sneak Attack and not based on
  level.)
- What is the DC on the sickened effect?
- Does the sickened effect work at all if I don't have any Alchemist
  levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require *house-ruling*, otherwise they will never become sickened, since you have **no alchemist levels**.

It also would deal 1d6 damage, as it **replaces the bomb's damage** by your Sneak Attack's damage. So, the discovery does nothing really to bomber rogues.

The DC of your bombs should be 10+INT modifier (no alchemist levels).

For every other question, check the [alchemist's bomb class feature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Bomb-Su-):

> These bombs act as alchemist's bombs

Answer (score 0):

Often, when some feature lets other classes emulate class features, Paizo does a sloppy work of leaving stuff out and by that making the new feature useless.

But we can extrapolate from how other, similar features, work at what is the most likely RAI.

Similar features have the wording: "Treat your X levels as Y levels for this feature." Lets assume this was intended to work that way, too and was left out because of page count or sloppy work. Now we get:

> A rogue with this talent can make a number of bombs per day equal to her Intelligence modifier (minimum 1). These bombs act as alchemist's bombs, except they deal damage equal to the damage dealt by the rogue's sneak attack (the rogue doesn't add her Intelligence modifier to this damage). *Treat your rogue levels as alchemist levels for this feature*

Now Cytillesh Bombs starts to make sense and this is what you were looking for:

- Your Cytillesh Bombs deal an amount of d4 equal to the amount of sneak attack dice you do. (whether that only includes dice from rogue levels is unclear)
- The sickened condition lasts for a number of rounds equal to your rogue level
- The DC is 10+ int mod + 1/2 rogue level

Comment: This is true, however that kind of wording is commonly seen on archetypes, which replace one ability for another. We have to keep in mind that the rogue is gaining a ranged SA that attacks an area with a total of 9 squares for his rogue talent. Unless we see an errata about it, it is house ruling.

Comment: Even the rogue archetype that allows for sneak attack on throw weapons will affect only a single target.
For reference: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo---rogue-archetypes/underground-chemist

Comment: The rogue is gaining int mod/day bombs when he takes the bomber talent. The Cytillesh Bombs trades a reduction in  damage for a sickening effect (with the possibility of memory loss), same as an alchemist could. And he has way more bombs/day

Answer (score -1):

Considering that none of these things give you Alchemist levels or explicitly state that you should treat your rogue level as your alchemist level then I'd say that this won't do much.

In particular as RAW

- Your Cytillesh Bombs deal an amount for damage equal to d4 + 1d4 per odd-numbered level. (This is a flat-replacement of the damage they normally do, regardless of your damage being different from an Alchemists)
- The sickened condition lasts 0 rounds (You have 0 alchemist levels)
- The DC is 10 + INT modifier (Your bombs act like alchemist bombs, but you have no alchemist levels)

Otherwise they gain all the benefits that alchemist bombs would gain, ignoring any benefits related to or requiring alchemist levels.

Comment: Anyone care to make comments as to why I'm getting downvoted?